# Compatibility of oldish iPhones, Apple's policy, future perspective

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm shopping for a used iPhone. I would not use it as a personal phone, just as a device to explore Apple's apps, for professional reasons.

I wonder what older models are still compatible with recently launched apps developed for new devices.

Is there some official road map about support from Apple and back compatibility policy?  How far back in iPhone version can I safely go to buy a cheap device that will last at least one year?

Comment: iPhone 5s would be the oldest choice, but it will probably not get iOS 12

Answer (score 3):

Here's the list of iPhones that currently support iOS 11:

- iPhone 5S
- 6
- 6 Plus
- 6S
- 6S Plus
- SE
- 7
- 7 Plus
- 8
- 8 Plus
- iPhone X

With the exception of the last 3, you can find reasonably inexpensive (probably not 'cheap') used iPhones that should last for another 1-3 years.  Apple doesn't post roadmaps as to upcoming devices or the iOS versions that support.